# installing particular version of node with homebrew is giving error

Tags: node.js

I neeed to install node version 10 and has followed below steps

- brew install node@10
- brew link node@10

above command gives error, thus tried

- brew link node@10 --force

Now I'm getting error

```
If you need to have this software first in your PATH instead consider running:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

I've checked .bash_profile and above entry does exist, not getting why above error keeps on showing ?

Comment: That isn't an error! It is just information. Don't worry about it if you have already done it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As commented by @quentin, this is not an error, it is an informational message.

Secondly, I prefer using the package `n` for installing a specific version of Node. https://www.npmjs.com/package/n

Initially, you get the default version of node installed. And then you use `n` to play around with the Node versions.

Install n - `$ npm install -g n`  
Installing node 10 - `$ n 10` 
Installing node stable - `$ n stable` 
Installing node latest - `$ n latest` 
Installing node lts - `$ n lts`

Comment: Thanks for clarification, so you're saying *n* is better than homebrew on Mac ?

Comment: I am saying, n is better to maintain different versions of node. Try it, you will be blown away.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you are still running an older node version. First, try to uninstall it with `brew uninstall node@8` assuming that node 8 is installed.

**Then**

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies --force node
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies --force icu4c
brew install icu4c
brew unlink icu4c && brew link icu4c --force
brew install node@10
```

I experienced the same problem few days ago and I found tis blog post helpful: [Mac Brew Node 10 upgrade](https://medium.com/@mahcloud/mac-brew-node-10-upgrade-55d3e910eebb)